# Condition for stacked bodies to *move together* under friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I was given a question in a mock test series:

> Three blocks A, B and C of masses $2\,\text{kg}$, $3\,\text{kg}$ and $4\,\text{kg}$ are placed as shown. Coefficient of friction between A and B is 0.5 and that between B and C is 0.1. Maximum force $F$ that can be applied horizontally on to A such that three blocks **move together** is _________ ($g=10\,\text{m}/\,\text{s}^2$).

> [image]

> Options:
>
> - $12.22\,\text N$
> - $13\,\text N$
> - $11.25\,\text N$
> - $15\,\text N$

My beef is the part where they ask us to find to force so that the blocks **move together**. Does this make any sense?

If we assume that by **move together**, it is meant that the blocks remain in same relative position to each other, the calculations come out wrong.
From the options we know that, $F>10\,\text{N}$. As such, if **move together** means block remain in same relative position to each other, then the acceleration of all the blocks must be same, i.e $$\frac{F-f_{ab}}{m_A}=\frac{f_{ab}-f_{bc}}{m_B}=\frac{f_{bc}}{m_C}$$

We know, $F>10\,\text{N}$ and $f_{{ab}_{\text{max}}}=10\,\text{N}$. So $f_{ab}=f_{{ab}_{\text{max}}}=10\,\text{N}$. Again  $f_{ab}>f_{{bc}_{\text{max}}}=5\,\text N$. So $f_{bc}=5\,\text N$ Hence now we know the values.

But on placing the values, the condition is not fulfilled. Hence I don't think this is what the question means.

Hence what does **move together** mean in this context? Can someone help me out?

Comment: "Move together" means the blocks do not slide over each other i.e. all three blocks remain in the same relative position and accelerate as a single unit.

Comment: How can you plug in values into your equation to check it if you don't know $f_{ab},f_{bc}$? (But the equation *is* correct; you're just using it wrong.)

Comment: @HTNW F>10 N=$f_{{ab}_{max}}$. So $f_{ab}=f_{{ab}_{max}}=10 N$. $f_{ab}>f_{{bc}_{max}}=5N$ So $f_{bc}=5N$ Hence now we know the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Calculate $F$ as a function of the acceleration of the center of mass of the three blocks; the only external force on the set of three blocks is F.

With no slip, this acceleration of the center of mass is the acceleration of each block.

For no slip, the forces of friction on block A and block C can be any value from zero up to $μ_{block}N_{block}$ where $μ_{block}$ is the coefficient of friction and $N_{block}$ is the normal force .  So calculate the maximum force of friction on block A and block C.

(2) Perform a force balance on block A and block C, and calculate the maximum acceleration allowed to prevent all forces of friction from exceeding their maximum.

With the maximum acceleration from (2), and F as a function of this acceleration from (1), calculate $F_{max}$.

I calculate $F_{max}$ as 11.25 N.  Also, the acceleration is 1.25 $ {m \over {sec^2}}$, the force of friction between A and B is 8.75 N and the force of friction between B and C is 5 N.

Comment: "....and calculate the maximum acceleration allowed to prevent all forces of friction from exceeding their maximum."---can you please elaborate this? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: If any frictional force exceeds its maximum static value sliding occurs; therefore, all frictional forces must be no greater than their maximum static value.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is assuming that the frictional force $f_{AB}$ tries to fully counter the push $F,$ such that it reaches its maximum ($|f_{AB}|\leq\mu_{AB}m_Ag=10\,\mathrm{N}$) whenever $F>10\,\mathrm{N}.$ It doesn't; even when $F<10\,\mathrm{N},$ $f_{AB}$ does not completely counter it. That just isn't a valid physical principle. Rather, you should start with your relation $$\frac{F-f_{AB}}{m_A}=\frac{f_{AB}-f_{BC}}{m_B}=\frac{f_{BC}}{m_C}.$$

This correctly describes a necessary and sufficient condition for "the blocks moving together." You can *solve* this equation for $f_{AB},f_{BC}$ to find the frictional forces that *would* be necessary for the blocks to move together (as a function of $F$): $$\begin{gathered}f_{AB}=\ldots\text{(something involving $F$)}\ldots\\f_{BC}=\ldots\text{(something involving $F$)}\ldots\end{gathered}$$ Then you may take the inequalities $f_{AB}\leq f_{AB,\text{max}},f_{BC}\leq f_{BC,\text{max}}$ and turn them into bounds on $F$. You find one of the answer choices.

Comment: "Your mistake is assuming that the frictional force fAB
tries to fully counter the push F, such that it reaches its maximum "-- how and why is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: $f_{AB}$ is responsible for transmitting some part of $F$ from $A$ to $B+C.$ But it doesn't transmit all of $F$! Some of it intuitively goes into $A$ only to make it accelerate. So $f_{AB}$ is always only trying to counter some force smaller than $F$.

Answer (score 0):

> if move together means blocks remain in same relative position to each other, then the acceleration of all the blocks must be same, i.e $$\frac{F-f_{ab}}{m_A}=\frac{f_{ab}-f_{bc}}{m_B}=\frac{f_{bc}}{m_C}$$

Yes, true.

> We know, $F>10N = f_{{ab}_{max}}$

No, this is not true. $f_{{ab}_{max}}$ could easily be larger than 10 N. Why should it be equal to 10 N? The 10 N was just you "guessing" from sneak peaking at the answers. Yes, it appears from the answer options that the maximum force, $F$, must be larger than 10 N. But it also has to be larger than 11 N. Or larger than, say, 8 N. Why did you pick the 10 N?

The 10 N is just a random choice you made, so there is no reason to think that $f_{{ab}_{max}}$ has got anything to do with 10 N. Especially not that $f_{{ab}_{max}}=10\;\mathrm N$. Also, I don't see why $f_{bc}$ should be equal to 5 N.

Instead, to solve this I would simply use the friction formula that I have for static friction. I could use that formula to find expressions for the forces in between the blocks. That should do the trick and solve the task.

Comment: 10 is not a random choice. $f_{{ab}_{max}}=0.5*2*10=10 N$. Since all options are greater than 10 N, maximum friction force acts.

Comment: @AlphaDelta Ahh, I see. Thank you for the clarification.You use the following formula, I presume, $$f_{ab,max}=\mu_s n=\mu_smg=0.5\cdot 2\,\mathrm{kg} \cdot 10\,\mathrm{m/s^2},$$ to reach the conclusion that $f_{ab,max}=10\,\mathrm N$. I agree. Then you state that $$f_{ab}=f_{ab,max},$$ meaning you are assuming that the maximum static friction has been achieved. This might not be the case. Static friction only has to be large enough to bring along all the other boxes. But this doesn't mean that we are at the edge of what static friction can withstand.